# why does SQL server consider SS as an Umlaut-S (ß)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

When I run the below query:

```
select charindex('ß','COMMISSIONING')
```

it returns a 6.

I specifically chose ß for a function as I thought it very unlikely to appear in any of my data. This was working perfectly fine for several weeks but now all of the sudden it's detecting ß where there is no ß and therefore screwing up my function.

Will someone please tell me what's caused this?

I'm using SQL server 2016

Comment: `ß`  is not the "beta sign"  it's an "umlaut S" and at least in German, an uppercase `ß` is written as `SS` (because there is no upper case version of `ß`) - but this should depend on the locale/encoding your server is using.

Comment: my SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') is Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: The beta sign would be `β` the umlaut S is `ß`

Comment: I believe it's a "scharfes S", not an umlaut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, as discussed in the comments, `SS` is an "uppercase" `ß`. If you don't want the characters to match you need your collation to be case sensitive. For the below, the value returned for both `CHARINDEX` expressions is `0`:

```
SELECT C, charindex('ß',V.C)
FROM (VALUES('COMMISSIONING' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)) V(C);

SELECT C, charindex('ß',V.C)
FROM (VALUES('COMMISSIONING' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI)) V(C);
```